# Use matlab code in python or get something similar

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, matlab-engine

In my program in need to reconstruct matlab code in python but not in very low level. The problem is that i got following lines of matlab

```
p = sobolset(problem_size, 'Skip', 1e4, 'Leap', 1e3);
p = scramble(p, 'MatousekAffineOwen');
rand0 = net(p, pop_size);
```

And I'm not able to reconstruct it on my own. Didn't find python functions in python libraries that would do exacly the same. So my question is if i could easly blend in this matlab code to python code or do someone have other idea how I can deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is probably to use either [MATLAB Compiler SDK](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-python-application-with-matlab-code.html) to generate a Python package from your MATLAB code or to use [MATLAB Engine for Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html).

If you are going to share this code with others that don't have a MATLAB installation or if you're running on a machine that doesn't have a MATLAB installation, you CANNOT use MATLAB Engine. Compiler SDK does require you to have that specific license though. If you are licensed through a university, you probably already have access to that license.